# Thinfinity Remote Desktop Workstation will not connect via RDP

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, thin-client

I am using Thinfinity Remote Desktop Workstation to connect to another computer on my home network. This had been setup on my network earlier this year. However, the server it is running on was recently rebuilt, so it is a fresh server install.

When using the web interface, Screen Sharing and File Sharing both work as expected. However, Remote Desktop will sit and spin with the message "Trying to establish a connection..." After several minutes, it will fail with the unhelpful "Failed to establish a connection."

Troubleshooting techniques already tried:

- Check the logs *(there seems to be nothing on the server, and the client is just a browser)*
- Turn off Windows Firewall (!) only temporarily *(no difference)*
- Try computers inside and outside the local network *(they all do the same thing)*

This may seem an overly broad question, and there isn't much to go on here, but this exact setup was working just a few weeks ago before the server was rebuilt.

**Is there a software setting in Thinfinity that I may not have setup correctly?**

I am using Thinfinity Remote Desktop Workstation v3.0.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. There is an issue connecting with Remote Desktop for **the very first time**.

Using the browser client, the very first time you connect to the server, you must first view the **Config** properties for the Remote Desktop module (pictured below).

You do not need to change anything, and you don't even need to look at all the tags. Just tap **Config** and then tap **Back**. From then on, connections from any browser client will ask you for your credentials and connect normally.

[image: thinfinity - rdp - step 1]

[image: thinfinity - rdp - step 1]